# crypto.randomBytes is not a function in angular

Tags: angular

I am importing [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet) in angular4,

```
import EthereumWallet from 'ethereumjs-wallet';
var wallet = EthereumWallet.generate();
const jsV3 = wallet.toV3(passwd);
```

the code inside the library shown as below

```
var privKey = crypto.randomBytes(32)
```

throws out an error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is
>   not a function TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function
>   TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function
>       at Function.webpackJsonp.../../../../ethereumjs-wallet/index.js.Wallet.generate

how to solve it ?

Comment: The amount of rep you have, one would think you'd know how to ask a question. One line of code isn't really helpful to diagnose a problem :)

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run

> *npm install crypto-browserify --save*

and after, you need create a file to fix (workaround)... like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// PACKAGE_ERROR and FILE_ERROR is shown on your error
fs.readFile('./node_modules/[PACKAGE_ERROR]/[FILE_ERROR]', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  var result = data.replace('require(\'crypto\');', 'require(\'crypto-browserify\');');

  fs.writeFile('./node_modules/[PACKAGE_ERROR]/[FILE_ERROR]', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });

});
```

Now, you need add the postinstall code on package.json

```
...
"scripts":{
"postinstall":"node [fixFileName].js",
...
```

And to finish, run:

> *npm install*
>   *ng serve* OR *ng build*

I hope this helps!

Comment: When I try this, I get:
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './node_modules/[PACKAGE_ERROR]/[FILE_ERROR]']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: './node_modules/[PACKAGE_ERROR]/[FILE_ERROR]' }